# Redis crashed as python runs for over a certain period of time

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery

im currently handling a project which involved with flask, celery and redis. What im trying to do here now is to allow celery to perform same task in a multiple workers. my problem that im facing right now is that my redis keeps crashing whenever it reaches to the maximum memory capacity and i had to manually flush the memoryDB in the redis manager. in this project i separated to few layouts as shown below:

```
new test
|___ __init__.py
|___ all.py
|___ celery_utils.py
|___ factory.py
|___ task.py
|___ utils.py
|___ celery_worker.py
|___ run.py
```

**init**.py

```
from celery import Celery

def make_celery(app_name = __name__):
    redis_uri = "redis://localhost:6379/6"
    return Celery(app_name, backend=redis_uri, broker=redis_uri)
celery = make_celery()
```

task.py

```
from liveapp import celery
from datetime import datetime
from celery import shared_task
import re
from numpy import array, concatenate
from .utils import series_to_supervised,model_retrain, model_repredict, model_predict
import pyodbc
import gc

@celery.task()
def process_data(data):
    *perform some data cleaning and prediction*
```

run.py

```
from liveapp import factory
import liveapp
from waitress import serve

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = factory.create_app(celery = liveapp.celery)
    serve(app, host='127.0.0.1',port=50000)
```

celery_worker.py

```
from liveapp import celery
from liveapp.factory import create_app
from liveapp.celery_utils import init_celery
app = create_app()
init_celery(celery, app)
```

celery_utils.py

```
def init_celery(celery,app):
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)     
    celery.Task = ContextTask
```

factory.py

```
from flask import Flask
import os
from .celery_utils import init_celery

PKG_NAME = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)).split("/")[-1]

def create_app(app_name=PKG_NAME, **kwargs):
    app = Flask(app_name)
    if kwargs.get("celery"):
        init_celery(kwargs.get("celery"), app)
    from liveapp.all import bp

    app.register_blueprint(bp)
    return app
```

all.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, make_response,jsonify,request
import os
from .task import process_data

bp = Blueprint("all", __name__)
@bp.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello!"

@bp.route("/api/live", methods=["POST"])
def live():
    if request.is_json:
        data = request.get_json()
    process_data.delay(data)

    return  make_response(jsonify({"message":"JSON received"}), 200)
```

now, running this flask is not the problem. when i was checking my redis, everything seems to be fine, where memory usage was below 5MB and max memory was 32GB. when i leave it to let the python run for 3 days, and come back ended up to see that my redis crashed and i have to restart it, flushing the memoryDB as it has reached the maximum capacity of the memory. been doing this quite often and i want to know if there's a way to deal with it. i was thinking to flush the memoryDB everytime i finish a task, but im not sure how to do it.

any guidance for this?